# org.parceler.Parcel: No corresponding property found for constructor parameter when constructor contains boolean fields

Tags: android, kotlin, parceler

I meet first time with this problem. I noticed that above exception is throw when @ParcelConstructor contains boolean fields. Maybe have you got any solutions to put in boolean values to constructor
Regards
Shogun

Comment: Use `Parcelize` soo much easier (this is part of kotlin experimental features, but for me it is quite stable).

Comment: Provide an example so I can help?  Just tried this in Java (whar Parceler was built for) and it works flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

In this case, you need to add @ParcelProperty.

One example:

```
@Parcel(Parcel.Serialization.BEAN)
private data class Model @ParcelConstructor constructor(
    @ParcelProperty("valid") val isValid: Boolean
)
```